# Не запускается приложение через Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

При попытке запустить приложение в Android Studio на реальном устройстве, приложение не устанавливается! Ну... Сначала устанавливается (антивирус пишет, что приложение проверено), а потом оно пропадает (так и не запустив `Activity`). Приложение — Hello World. В Eclipse все работало нормально.

Вот вывод в консоль:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: lenovo-lenovo_a536-0123456789ABCDEF
Uploading file
    local path: D:\Android Aplication\myApplication\DictionaryDemo_3\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.dictionarydemo_3
Installing com.dictionarydemo_3
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.dictionarydemo_3"
WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.dictionarydemo_3
Success


    Launching application: com.dictionarydemo_3/com.dictionarydemo_3.MainActivity.
    DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start  -n "com.dictionarydemo_3/com.dictionarydemo_3.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
    WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
    Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.dictionarydemo_3/.MainActivity }
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.dictionarydemo_3/.MainActivity } from null (pid=4359, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10187
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2228)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Как исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно было добавить в код `Activity` (в файле `Manifest.xml`):

---

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```